# Какое исключение бросить в Delphi, чтобы его можно было отловить внутри .NET

Tags: c#, delphi, исключения

Есть неуправляемая библиотека, написанная на Delphi, и графическая оболочка, написанная на C#. Нужно сделать так, чтобы библиотека на Delphi могла бросить исключение, которое можно было бы обработать на уровне C#. Сейчас в библиотеке на Delphi бросается кастомное исключение, но до .NET доходит `SEHException`, на которое блок `try/catch` не действует. Что нужно бросить на Delphi, чтобы всё заработало?

Comment: А `try { /*код*/ } catch {}` (именно так, а не `catch (Exception)`) не помогает? Как у вас устроен interop?

Comment: Через `LoadLibrary` загружается нужная функция (пользователь может её выбрать), потом `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` и запускаем. Блок `catch` и так без конкретного исключения.

Comment: @Modus: Вам нужно просто поймать, или вы хотите получить конкретный нативный тип исключения? Второе, боюсь, невозможно :(

Comment: Да хотя бы поймать. Проблема в том, что try-catch не работает

Comment: @Modus: Ах, даже так? Нормальные нативные исключения должны оборачиваться в `SEHException` и ловиться наряду со всеми прочими.

Попробуйте [вот это](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/All-about-Corrupted-State-Exceptions-in-NET4.aspx), может, проблема именно здесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключения в Delphi и исключения в .NET - две большие разницы, они никак не совместимы. Единственный выход, который вижу, это модифицировать вашу Delphi DLL-ку так, чтобы методы возвращали error codes вместо исключений (так же, как это делает WinAPI), а затем написать wrapper на .NET, который будет эти коды ошибок переводить в исключения.

Есть еще вариант для экстремалов - переписать вашу DLL-ку на Delphi в COM библиотеку, и заюзать ее в .NET через COM Interop. Мне кажется, исключения там должны ловиться все, но я сам не пробовал.

Но я бы выбрал первый вариант, дешево и сердито.